# Create struct/protocol/class with no external properties in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols

I have a class that wants to return a token which it alone can create and read, but can be handed to an client class which cannot do anything with it except give it back. The token contains a value. How can I design this so it only has private properties/methods but looks completely opaque to public. I don't want to do any casting, it needs to be type safe internal to the owning class. Swift 4.x.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to make it "get-only"

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If you want the client class to be able to read only and not modify it, then you can do what @user770 said and make it a `get-only` property. If, however, you don't want the client class to read it at all, then I don't see the point of allowing the client class to access it; only to give it back.

Comment: It is more of a theoretical problem, wondering if in swift there is way to build a type safe (for the dispensing class) equivalent to using id or void* and hiding the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my feeble attempt. I don't think there is a way to make a class that is completely opaque in the sense that you hide the names of all its members, but you can make them inaccessible.

```
struct Token {
    //everyone can see this property exists, but only 
    //classes defined in this file can see its value
    fileprivate let value: String
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you'll need a class for issuing and validating the tokens. It will need to be able to see inside the token.

```
class TokenManager {
    func requestToken() -> Token {
        return Token(value: "a magic token value")
    }
    func isValid(token: Token) -> Bool {
        //to inspect the token's value, this class needs to be defined  
        //in the same file as the Token
        return token.value == "a magic token value"
    }
}
```

The consumer of the token would request a token like this:

```
    let myToken = TokenManager().requestToken()
```

It would know that the token has a `value` property, but would be unable to access it:

```
    //print(myToken.value) //'value' is inaccessible due to 'fileprivate' protection level
```

But the `TokenManager` could inspect the token's value:

```
    let isValid = TokenManager().isValid(token: myToken)
    print(isValid) //true
```

You would undoubtedly want to pass some data into the `requestToken` method that you would validate in the `isValid` method, but that is, as they say, an exercise left for the reader.

Note you can't make `Token` a `fileprivate struct` because then nobody could get a token.

Comment: Maybe its just not possible in the language to have a Thing without exposing something about the Thing and not using casting somewhere.